# Adding a custom text next to a specific product attribute label in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label, product-variations

Trying to add text (best inside a div) next to the title/label for a variation (i.e. SIZE) **without editing the woocommerce page template**.

**Pseudocode:**

```
function my_text_after_variation (){
  if attribute pa_size exists {
    echo label for pa_size;
    echo <div> MY TEXT </div>;
}else{
   return;
}};
```

Every help is highly welcome.

[image: Move the sizing Guide text next to the sizes attribute label]

Comment: This question is just unclear… The product variation title is located in cart items on cart page and checkout pages. Now the attribute title/label, is located on variable products dropdowns in single product pages. So you should provide a screen shot or a live link and better explanations, please. Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - merci mon amis :) i have added the screenshot to explain what i'm after. I need this only on the single product pages and nowhere else. Thanks Loic

Comment: Ok fine I have answered and is quiet simple and light. As the display is not inline using a `<div>` tag, the appended custom text goes next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display a custom text just after a specific attribute label name, you will use this a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_attribute_label`** dedicated filter hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$name;

    if( $taxonomy == 'pa_size' )
        $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';

    return $label;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it //also// changes the dropdown which isn't so nice :/

Answer (score 2):

If you can not edit the woocommerce page template, try to use jQuery.
For example:

```
$('.pa_size label').after('<span class="some-text">some text</text>');
```

If you need to use variable text, you can create object with this variable using '[wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)' and get it from this object:

function.php

```
// Localize the script with your data
$data_array = array(
  'some_text' => __( 'Some text to insert', 'my-domain' ),
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $data_array );
```

jQuery:

```
$('.pa_size label').after(object_name.some_text);
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander | I need to echo/output a php var inside this new div and can't get it working with the following code adapted from your answer: ` function add_div_after_pa_size () {
global $product_id
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.ivpa_title').after('<div class="some-text"> '<?php echo $product_id; ?>'</div></text>');
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_div_after_pa_size' );`