# WooCommerce: How to add custom text between variation title (label) and dropdown selector

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We would like to add (fixed) custom text in between the title/label of the product variation and the dropdown selector like indicated below.
[image]

We already tried following code

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$name;

    if( $taxonomy == 'pa_bodenankertyp' )
        $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY custom TEXT', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';

    return $label;
}
```

from this post
[Adding a custom text next to a specific product attribute label in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667210/adding-a-custom-text-next-to-a-specific-product-attribute-label-in-woocommerce)

but it does not work.

Any idea or hints what is wrong are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using this hook since you change it in multiple places - places where you don't want any changes. I would suggest overwriting the specific WooCommerce template. For that, go to your child theme and create the following folder structure:

> your-child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/

Now you need to create a PHP file named `variable.php` in there and paste the following code inside:

```
<?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.5.5
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

$attribute_keys  = array_keys( $attributes );
$variations_json = wp_json_encode( $available_variations );
$variations_attr = function_exists( 'wc_esc_json' ) ? wc_esc_json( $variations_json ) : _wp_specialchars( $variations_json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo $variations_attr; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', __( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">
                            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label>
                            <div class="custom-label"><?= __('MY custom TEXT', 'woocommerce') ?></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
                                    array(
                                        'options'   => $options,
                                        'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                        'product'   => $product,
                                    )
                                );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <?php
                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_single_variation. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                 *
                 * @since 2.4.0
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                 * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation' );

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_variation.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_form' ); ?>
</form>

<?php
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' );
```

In this code you will find your `div`. If you need any checks, just put them around your `div`. In your case I would check the variable `$attribute_name`.

Comment: Thanks for your input/feedback, this will certainly work for the setup we have now. However, won't this cause problems, if I have more than one attribute for variations? I mean that I think the custom text would appear after each variation attribute title/label then. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct. But check my question. As I told, you need to add a custom check around by using the `$attribute_name` variable to be sure it's only where it should be. Since you know how to use a hook, I think you can do this! Just give it a try :-)