# WooCommerce show content after variation labels

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to add content after variation name.

I find this hook and saw it's working before, but no on my test it's not :(

I want to ask, is there another hook/working method I can use to add content?

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3);
function custom_attribute_label($label, $name, $product){
    $taxonomy = 'pa_' . $name;

    if ($taxonomy == 'pa_size')
        $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';

    return $label;
}
```

Code reference:
[Adding a custom text next to a specific product attribute label in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48690467/15040627)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `$label` variable, it will return the name without `"pa_"` prefix.  Some variations have `"pa_"` prefixes and some don't.

So you don't need to create an extra variable (i.e $taxonomy). Just use `$label` variable, like this:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3);

function custom_attribute_label($label, $name, $product)
{

    if ('Logo' == $label) 
    {
        $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
    }

    return $label;
}
```

[image]

---

You could use `switch` statement for checking multiple conditions like this:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3);

function custom_attribute_label($label, $name, $product)
{

    switch ($label) 
    {
        case 'Logo':
            $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT AFTER LOGO', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
            break;
        case 'Color':
            $label .= '<div class="custom-label">' . __('MY TEXT AFTER COLOR', 'woocommerce') . '</div>';
            break;
    }

    return $label;
}
```

[image]